# On Debian 9, is /root part of the /home partition?

Tags: partition, directory-structure, disk-encryption

I am encrypting my `/home` partition and I would also like any secrets `/root` (not `/`) contains to be encrypted. Is the `/root` folder considered part of the `/home` partition by default, or do I need to explicitly add that folder to the encrypted volume? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/root` is normally on the root partition. It's meant to be available even if something goes wrong and other partitions can't be mounted.

Note that `/root` only contains what you put yourself. Sensitive data created by the system ends up under `/etc` or `/var`.

These days, with most CPUs having accelerated AES instructions, disk encryption is very cheap. So if you're concerned about confidential data outside of your home directory, you should encrypt the whole system except `/boot`. This is a good idea anyway because confidential data can end up in other places: wifi passwords in `/etc`, printed documents in `/var/spool/cups`, logs showing what wifi networks you connected to and when in `/var/log`, etc.

If you really want to encrypt only `/home` and not the whole system, which I repeat is not a good idea, you can make `/root` a symbolic link:

```
mv /root /home
ln -s /home/root /
```

Comment: Thanks! I am definitely not advocating _adding_ secrets to `/root`, but in case some sudoer decides to do so, I want those secrets to be encrypted at rest. This works.